Passing contents of a pdf file to a pyspark dataframe
I am trying to make a new column from a pdf file text extracted with tika to a pyspark dataframe, but I can't put the text into this new column
I have two functions, the first one extracts the text with tika; I put the text in a .txt file because I noted that if I return the text directly, it displays nothing in the dataframe
def extract_text_with_tika(doc_file):
    txt = ""
    meta = parser.from_file(doc_file, requestOptions={'timeout': 300})
    
    if meta['content']:
        for i, line in enumerate(meta['content'].split('\n')):
            if len(line.strip()) > 0:
                txt = txt + line.replace('\n', ' ')
    else:
        return ""
        
    txt_file_name = doc_file.replace(".pdf", ".txt")
    
    with open(txt_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(txt)
        
    file = open(txt_file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    clean_text = file.read()
    
    return clean_text

The second function uses extract_text_with_tika to iterate over a folder of possible options where the .pdf file could be and it is like this:
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def process_file(body, fname):
    txt = ""
    tmp_path =  f"/mnt/hdata/files/content/{body}/{fname}"
    sent_path1 = f"/mnt/repositorio/acuerdos/{body}/{fname}" 
    
    if path.exists(sent_path1):
        shutil.copyfile(sent_path1, tmp_path) #copy the pdf file to tmp_path
        txt = extract_text_with_tika(tmp_path) #extract the text from tmp_path
    else:
        print("No path found")

    return txt        

The dataframe has two important attributes named 'body' and 'file_name', those are the attributes I use as parameters for my function
So now I call process_file like this using a UDF as decorator:
df_query = spark.sql("select * from Table;")
df = df_query.withColumn("text", process_file("body", "file_name")

and the output does not show the text, like this:
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
|body          |           file_name|          text|
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
|          4010|40100000318789150...|              |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+

I know this issue is not from tika, I think I am doing something wrong with the text format or when calling my function because I tested the function with the files and they show correctly the extracted text on the 'text' attribute when passing the text "directly" using lit(); the code I used and acted as expected is the following:
f = open('/mnt/hdata/files/content/4010/40100000318789150001001.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
text = f.read()
dfquery = spark.sql("select * from Table;")
df1 = dfquery.withColumn("text", lit(text))

How do I put the text in this column? The dataframe size is about 2M rows. I have tried different approaches like not using decorators and I can't make the text to show on the dataframe, I think maybe the UDF doesn't identify paths, any help would be very appreciated. Also, I am using zeppelin on a remote server

not sure if this is the issue, but your return txt line is outside the function body.

Thank you for the observation, it was a typo
